# regular expression to match first two numbers before semicolon

Tags: regex

I have a strings like the one as follows:

```
-9.853418333333334 35.020405 0.0 0.0;-9.854273333333333 35.02038 0.0 0.0;-9.85452 35.01970166666667 0.0 0.0;-9.854205 35.019618333333334 0.0 0.0;-9.853418333333334 35.020405 0.0 0.0;
```

and I want use a regular expression to match the semicolon and the previous two numbers and spaces before each semicolon so I can replace them all with a comma and a space like this.

```
-9.853418333333334 35.020405, -9.854273333333333 35.02038, -9.85452 35.01970166666667, -9.854205 35.019618333333334, -9.853418333333334 35.020405,
```

If all the two numbers before the semicolon were always 0.0, I wouldn't bother to use a regular expression, but unfortunately, sometimes they are more complicated as follows:

```
-10.134578333333334 34.945479999999996 1433.7 2.5;-10.134636666666667 34.94678 1455.4 2.1;-10.133980000000001 34.946913333333335 1457.5 2.2;-10.133958333333334 34.945555 1434.8 2.1;-10.134578333333334 34.945479999999996 1433.7 2.5;
```

I tried this:

```
\s.+?\s.+?;
```

But it selects every number that has a space before it, not just the first two before the semicolon. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a digit in place of any character (and remember to match a fraction!)

```
\s\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+;
```

Comment: Or more compact, `(?:\s\d+\.\d+){2};` so that you only once write the definition of the "space plus float".

Comment: @user1016274 Exactly! Thanks! (You may want to post it?)

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: [`(?: [0-9.]+){2};`](https://regex101.com/r/BHCvmH/1) (85 steps)

Details:

- `(?:)` Non capturing group
- `' '` Space
- `[0-9.]+` Match a single character present in the list between one and unlimited times
- `{2}` Matches exactly 2 times

Comment: Subtle difference to the accepted answer is that the match could contain from one to an unlimited number of dots.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this regular expression:

```
\s+\d+(\.\d+)?\s+\d+(\.\d+)?;
```

This can be tested [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cs%2B%5Cd%2B(%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F%5Cs%2B%5Cd%2B(%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F%3B&test_string=-9.853418333333334%2035.020405%200.0%200.0%3B-9.854273333333333%2035.02038%200.0%200.0%3B-9.85452%2035.01970166666667%200.0%200.0%3B-9.854205%2035.019618333333334%200.0%200.0%3B-9.853418333333334%2035.020405%200.0%200.0%3B&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

This expression matches the following components:

1. \s+ multiple spaces
2. \d+(.\d+)? first double
3. \s+ multiple spaces
4. \d+(.\d+)? second double or integer

Comment: A little remark: please don't forget to backslash a dot.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for posting multiple answers) I think we all were focused on proper matching of numbers, but it *may* appear that the task is actually just matching two non-space text fields followed by a semicolon:

```
(?:\s\S+){2};
```